# Allow a ToolItem to fill horizontally in a Toolbar

Tags: python, layout, gtk, pygtk, toolbar

SO.
I've been busy working on a project in python and pygtk. I want to have (at the top) a "Toolbar" with back, forward etc. buttons and a long Entry that would take the rest of the horizontal space. I don't get the desired effect, however, as the space the Entry takes is quite limited.

```
self.omnicont = gtk.ToolItem()

self.omni = gtk.Entry()
self.omnicont.add(self.omni)
```

I've tried set_child_packing (which doesn't apply to Toolbars, it seems). I couldn't find any other way.
The buttons I have are declared in this way:

```
self.bBack = gtk.ToolButton(gtk.STOCK_GO_BACK)
```

and similar, so I don't think it's possible to put buttons like this in an HBOx.

How can I have the Entry take all the available horizontal space and, if that's not possible, how could I get an HBox to contain buttons with the stock icons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accordingly to the [docs](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtktoolitem.html#method-gtktoolitem--set-expand) you can use:

```
set_expand(True)
```

on the item you want to expand.

Comment: Thanks @Vicent, I wast trying to do it the C# Propriety style forgetting that, though python has no private variables, there's __var